# Changing colour of types for VB.net in VS

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am currently working on a VB.NET project and the hardest thing that I am having trouble with is that everything is black and blue.

Having worked a lot with C#, I really like the way that types are colored differently.

I have tried going in and having a look at the "`Tools > Options > Fonts and Colors`" and the various "`User Types`" under "`Display Items`" is set to a different colour but its not reflecting that colour in the text editor.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Young whippersnappers today ... when I was a youngster we all had monochrome displays, usually green-screen! If you had three shades of green you were *lucky*. Oh, if only the hardest problem were the colour of types...

Comment: lol... Trust me I have bigger problems that this, but it is the one that is most annoying be atm. That and when I press enter it accepts the intellisense and puts in a new line break... Another C# to vb.net idiosyncrasy

Comment: I get the same problem when switching to c# from vb.net...I try to use space on the intellisense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the 'Keyword' colour, but this will also change, well all keywords (such as `Class` and `Function`), not just types.

Answer (score 0):

Down in the list is User Types as well as user types for delegates, enums, interfaces, and Value Types.

Comment: I have set these and it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how VS2010 handles it?  With the VB and C# teams working closer together now maybe this has already been addressed.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=922B4655-93D0-4476-BDA4-94CF5F8D4814&displaylang=en

--good luck with this - editor quirks can be the worst!
(excpet of course when your green screen dies...)  :)